# Minimizing length of fold of a standard sheet of paper

Tags: calculus

A standard $8.5$ inches by $11$ inches piece of paper is folded so that one corner touches the opposite long side and the crease ends on the adjacent short side, as shown in the picture below. What is the minimum length of the crease?

This is, in theory, a simple optimisation problem, however, my approach quickly deteriorated into angle chasing. How should I approach the question?

Thanks!

[image: Edit: Picture here, sorry!!!]

Comment: Where is "the picture below"? That may tell us if the "far end" of the crease ends on the opposite long side or opposite short side, or if either is possible here.

Answer (score 1):

*Just a hint about the set-up:*

If say the top left corner is at $A=(0,11)$ and it gets folded down to the right side $x=8.5$ so it winds up at $P(t)=(8.5,t),$ then the crease would be the intersection of the perpendicular bisector of segment $A\ P(t)$ with the sheet of paper. So parametrize this situation and hopefully proceed to get an expression for the length $L(t)$ of that intersection, so as to apply usual minimization techniques.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ and $x$ are the lengths respectively of the short sides and the distance from the right side to where the crease touches the bottom side ($x>S/2$ of course), the result should be $x=3/4\,S\,$ if the long sides were infinite.

Draw the right parallel to the short sides: you obtain two similar right triangles (why ?).

Written a proportion and applied Pythagoras to a third triangle, you get the square of the crease as $$\frac {2x^3}{2x-S}$$ Equal to $0$ the derivative.

It remains to study the compatibility with the length of the long sides.